# Range picker with just one calendar

Tags: reactjs

I use in my application range picker component from ant design.

```js
 <RangePicker
      onChange={onChange}
      dateRender={current => {
        const style = {};
        if (current.date() === 1) {
          style.border = "1px solid #1890ff";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
```

Now, when i want to set a time, clicking on the tag, appears 2 calendars as dropdown, but i want to see just one. I tried to hide the right calendar with `display: none`, but the arrow which allow to switch between month also disappears. How to display just one calendar for range picker?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-hill-noips?file=/index.js

Comment: This is how the DatePicker from antdesign is designed.  Can you describe how you want to select a range only showing one calendar?  Did you want to select two dates on the same calendar or did you want one calendar if you select the left and right dates.

Comment: @possum, the idea is next: when i will select a range from a month, the picker should work like now (to show that range with blue background), but if the second selected value is greater than end of the month, the calendar should allow to select that day (now it is disabled). Also if you select a date from one month and you want the second value to be from the second month, the picker should allow to change manually the month with right or left arrow. Please, let me know if you understand.